# Child Table Selections are Reset After "DialogOk" Event (Maximo - Jython Automation Script)

Tags: events, automation, event-handling, jython, maximo

**The Issue**: We are running Maximo 7.6.1 or greater; I have a custom application (no java class customizations) that includes a custom dialog, and this dialog is used to update data in the app.

My application includes 4 main tables, where the selected row in table 1 filters table 2, the selected row in table 2 filters table 3, and so on... this allows the user to manage data that is structured in a basic hierarchy.

Based on the users settings in the dialog, rows are manipulated/added in the application, and the data is refreshed and saved when the user clicks ok.

**The Problem**: Although the data is updating correctly when the user clicks Ok and the dialog closes, all the table selections are reset... so whatever record the user was working on - although updated correctly - is no longer displayed. This seems to happen due to the "**DialogOK**" event being triggerd... however, without running this event, the data does not update in the UI.

How can I ensure Maximo does not reset the selections after the dialog closes and data is updated?

Alternatively, I actually found I was able to access the databeans for each of the tables within my Jython script, and was able to get the index of each currently selected row... How can I set the current row of each databean/table to it's previous value ***after*** the "DialogOk" event completes? This could be a solution to manually reset the selection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   from psdi.common.context import UIContext
   from psdi.webclient.system.controller \
        import SessionContext, Utility, WebClientEvent

   context = UIContext.getCurrentContext()
   wcs = context.getWebClientSession()
   control = wcs.findControl('name of table')
   row = control.getCurrentRow()

   #do stuff that breaks the row

   control.setCurrentRow(row)
   control.rowChanged()
```